# Glimpse seems to be hanging my browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I've recently update all my web projects to mvc5 and the latest glimpse (asp.net 1.9,1.85 core and 1.53 mc5).  Even when I run remoted into my production server, it basically hangs the browser.

Is there a known problem here? how can I figure out what is going on?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an outstanding known issue.

The best thing to do is use your browser's F12/Networking tools to determine the size of `/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_request&requestId=...` request.

If that JSON response is too large, it may be causing your browser to work a little too hard. You can reduce the size of that payload by removing tabs that you aren't using.

Comment: I did forget to mention that I have "cache" tab installed. I removed that it it's running now, just very slow (I put a lot in server side cache)